# variable $USER or $USERNAME changing

Tags: linux, root, pam

i'm using `pam_script` to execute a script at logging

```
if [[ $USER = "root" ]]
then
     echo "root"
else
     echo " someone else"
fi
```

now the script is a bit complicated than this one, here when i try to logout and login with another account for example toto i get after executing this script => root witch is not the USER
any ideas in how to get the correct answer (root)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]; then
   echo "root"
else
   echo "someone else"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, i already tried this and when i execute a script as root without su it says am root

Comment: uid is always 0 for root user, other users will return non-zero value. if you execute this script as root user this will print root,if you login as another user and execute this script, this will print someone else.